# JNLP Client requests resource from server multiple times before checking jar

Tags: java, applet, classloader, jnlp

The server reports that the JNLP client requests resources multiple times before checking jar.

It may be the wished-for resource is requested up to 10 times from the server, before finally checking and finding the it in the loaded JAR-file.
My app is deployed as an applet using `dtjava.embed()` and a JNLP-file.
The applet does start, but only after a big delay for the 100+ requests it sends to the server first!

Any ideas on what is causing the redundant requests, and how to fix it?

Comment: It may appear to be similar, but isn't.  I tried the codebase_lookup-parameter before (and again now), but to no avail.  Also I see the requests coming in on the server (10 times pr rsc), as I run on a development server.

Comment: While I incorrectly thought this was a duplicate(A), I have now edited the question and voted to re-open on the grounds that it is 'clear'.   A) Noise deleted.  BTW +1 for your research & +1 for providing the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was actually this page which lead me to the solution: 
[Java WebStart slow, requesting libraries from invalid folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770807/java-webstart-slow-requesting-libraries-from-invalid-folder?rq=1)

I didn't know about indexing of JARs at all.  Now I do.  And as soon as I added an index to the JAR, the problem went away!

Thank you all.