# How can selected dependencies be included in INDEX.LIST using maven?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to included specific set of dependencies inside my `INDEX.LIST`, generated by `maven-jar-plugin`, my jar plugin looks like this

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
        <index>true</index>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>                        
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
          <!-- my entries -->
        </manifestEntries>
      </archive>
      <excludes>
        <!-- excluded files -->
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

and it includes every single dependency with compile `scope`, but that's not my goal, i want to have specific set of dependencies inside the `INDEX.LIST`, as a workaround i have managed to do it with `maven-antrun-plugin`,

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <configuration>
          <target>
            <unzip src="${project.build.directory}/${artifactId}-${version}.jar" dest="${project.build.directory}/tmp" />
            <replaceregexp file="${project.build.directory}/tmp/META-INF/INDEX.LIST" match="regex code place" flags="m" replace="" />
            <zip baseDir="${project.build.directory}/tmp" destfile="${project.build.directory}/tmp/${artifactId}-${version}.jar" />
            <move file="${project.build.directory}/tmp/${artifactId}-${version}.jar" toDir="${project.build.directory}" />
          </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

but i don's see this solution as a clean one, "building the `.jar`, then unzipping it, removing unnecessary jar's from `INDEX.LIST` and zipping it back." do you have any idea how can i do this with `maven` only? i don't like bringing the `ant` in the game and i don't like the process of opening already bundled jar.

changing the `scope` of dependency can not be the solution as well, i need them in compile `scope`.

will match appreciate the good idea's. Thanks in advance

Comment: An `INDEX.LIST` contains only packeges not information about dependencies...because a JAR file does not contain other dependencies

Comment: @khmarbaise is your comment solution ?

Comment: The first question is: Why do you like to have that in the `INDEX.LIST` file? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to solve issue similar to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770807/java-webstart-slow-requesting-libraries-from-invalid-folder

Comment: Is this true for JDK8,11 or even 17? The post is about 11 years old..  JavaWebStart? really using this kind of thing? Using this: https://openwebstart.com/ows/  ? Do you have a full working example which shows a problem/issue?

Comment: yes, it is True, I'm using JDK8 with java web start and can not replace it unfortunately. of course i have full working example, but can't share it, sorry.

Comment: So I repeat my question: What exactly is the problem? The links issue is not related to the INDEX.LIST file ... ? So why can't share an example to show the issue?

Comment: Problem is slow initialization of Application caused by the package which is added to `INDEX.LIST`, i do not need this package inside the `INDEX.LIST`, you are right, it it not related to `INDEX.LIST`, but it can be solved from there. Well it is solved, as you can see, i removed the unwanted package successfully and problem is solved, what i need now, is a clean solution for it.